# Adding Linux DataSource on Lucidworks Server

Tags: linux, datasource, documentum, emc, lucidworks

I am trying to create a datasource of linux server on Lucidworks using whicih i could be able to Index documents for Querying Search on it.Kindly Suggest the Way to implement it.
p.s.-Currently i am trying to use the NFS Server but unable to create the connection

Answer (score 0):

You just need to select File System if you are trying to create a Collection of a folder from your Linux server. 

The path to the directory then must look like this for example /directory/folder-name

Hope it helps!